# Sort/order UITableView by distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a plist to populate a UITableView using the following code:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Items" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *itemDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.itemList = itemDictionary[@"List of Items"];
```

The plist looks like this:

```
<key>List of Items</key>
<array>
    <<dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Name of Item 1</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Description of Item 1</string>
        <key>Latitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Longitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Name of Item 2</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Description of Item 2</string>
        <key>Latitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Longitude</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
```

I am able to set the title and subtitle (distance from coordinates) of each item in the cells using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.textLabel.text = self.itemList[indexPath.row][@"Name"];
            CLLocation *itemLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self.itemList[indexPath.row][@"Latitude"] doubleValue]
                                                           longitude:[self.itemList[indexPath.row][@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];
            CLLocationDistance itemDistance = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.f metres", itemDistance];
return cell;
 }
```

However, I would like to sort/order the table view by the nearest location (item). This could possibly be done by using the `itemDistance` float value or the whole `detailTextLabel.text` but I wouldn't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the  itemDistance in advance before populating it on UITableView;

```
for(int i=0; i< [self.itemList count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict [self.itemList objectAtIndex:i];  
    CLLocation *itemLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self.itemList[i][@"Latitude"] doubleValue]
                                                       longitude:[self.itemList[i][@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];
    CLLocationDistance itemDistance = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: itemDistance] forKey:@"itemDistance"];
```

}

```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemDistance"
ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
  NSArray *sortedArray = [self.itemList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

then load the sortedArray on UITableView. Plz note that i have not compiled the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply sort a tableview based on the data contained in the tableviewcells (only the visible tableview cells exist). You have to sort the data source of the table view, in your case the self.itemList. Make a new method that will calculate the distance for each item in self.itemList and then either sort self.itemList based on that distance, or make a new array with sorted values. Don't calculate the distance in the cellforrowatindexpath method if you want it sorted by that value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I made a new array for just the distances, how would I link the distance to the items array to use in cellforrowatindexpath? Also, would I be able to update the distance array from the locationmanager when the user changes location without making huge impact on RAM and CPU?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. You could make an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary. Each dictionary would contain the item from self.itemList and the distance, for example : 

@{@"item":self.itemList item, @"distance":calculated distance};

Then you sort the array of dictionaries based on each dictionary's @"distance" key

Comment: And yes you can update this array from the locationmanager as long as you have a reference to whatever viewcontroller is delegating the uitableview. You could have a public method on your viewcontroller that will recalculate distance, sort, and reload tableview data

Comment: How would get the latitude and longitude values for each item in the item array, calculate and add the distance to the new mutable array then grab the matching distance value (distance mutable array) of the item from the item array to use in the cellforrowatindexpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at 'NSSortDiscriptor'.

Sample:

```
NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Sort your `itemList` with this after you loaded it.

Comment: I do not have a distance property in the array as it's calculated using the coordinates from the array to the current location of the user.